# Unable to install sts in eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse, sts

I am trying to add the Spring tool suite plugin in to Eclipse (4.4),but I am getting below error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQsCa.jpg)

Comment: Show us the log as plain text. But Eclipse Luna (4.4) is now 8 years and 18 releases old, so it is probably too old for any modern software.

Comment: which will be the eclipse version supporting sts

Comment: I don't know about STS but you should start with the current release 2021-12.

Comment: The screenshot shows problems with a VMware vFabric plugin or/and update site, which you may have only because you have missed to keep your Eclipse and installed plugins up to date for years. Start with a fresh [Eclipse 2021-12](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) and install [Spring Tools 4 (aka STS 4)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-4-aka-spring-tool-suite-4) or with a fresh [Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse 4.13.1](https://spring.io/tools) which is the current Eclipse containing Spring Tools. Please make sure your software is up to date before asking.